# Lower bounds of inner products in a real Hilbert spaces

Tags: convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, convex-optimization, inner-products

let $H$ be a real Hilbert space and let $x,y\in H$ such that the coordinates of the vectors $x$ and $y$ can be positive or negative, are there any theorems that deal with a lower bound of $<x,y>$? Is there a way to assure that $<x,y>\geqslant0$ (besides the trivial approach by which take the vectors $x$ and $y$ to be such that  their coordinates are either all positive or  either all negative)  or $<x,y>\leqslant0$

Comment: Not without more information. Without more information the inner product could just be zero, of course. What do you want this for?

Comment: Define by $P: H\rightarrow C$  the orthogonal projection from $H$ to the closed convex subset $C$ and let $x,y\in H$. Is there a way or a theorem that assures that $<P(x), P(y)>\leq 0$ or  $<P(x), P(y)>\geq 0$? @QiaochuYuan

Comment: Depends on $C$? Without further information we could just have $C = H$, for example.

Comment: If you take $C=H$  than it is obvious that $<x,y>\leq 0$ or $<x,y>\geq 0$. What I meant was, is there a general approach to assure that for a set of points, denote by $S$, in $H$ such that we don't know whether their coordinates are negative or positive, is it possible to assure for every $x,y\in S$ that  $<P(x), P(y)>$ is only positive\negative? @QiaochuYuan

Comment: I no longer understand what you're asking. Are you asking when it's possible to prove "either $\forall x, y : \langle P(x), P(y) \rangle \ge 0$ or $\forall x, y : \langle P(x), P(y) \rangle \le 0$?" This is certainly false when $C = H$.

Comment: Read again my previous comment. I modified it. Thank you for your help. @QiaochuYuan

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking. You say that $H$ is a real Hilbert space, so isn't it *always* true that either $\langle x, y \rangle \le 0$ or $\langle x, y \rangle \ge 0$?

Comment: I want to assure that all of the points in $S$ satisfies only one of the following: $S:=x,y\in H : <x,y>\geq 0$ or  $S:=x,y\in H : <x,y>\leq 0}$ @QiaochuYuan

Comment: This is the question I was asking three comments ago about where the quantifiers are. I don't understand why you think this is true when $C = H$ so I think I'm still misunderstanding something but I can't tell what. Can you state your question *with quantifiers*?

Comment: I said it is obvious that once $C=H$ that you get that for any $x,y\in H$,  $<x,y>\geq 0$ or $<x,y>\leq 0$

Comment: Yes, but *isn't that always true*, with no other assumptions whatsoever on anything??? What's an example of a situation where that *isn't* true???

Comment: Yes, if $C=H$ than what you wrote is indeed true, but I want the points in  $S$ to satisfy only one of the inequlities.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought you were asking, but then I have no idea why you thought it was relevant to say "if you take $C = H$ then it is obvious that $\langle x, y \rangle \le 0$ or $\langle x, y \rangle \ge 0$."